# Use local time in Blazor WASM with BlazorEnableTimeZoneSupport disabled

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I assumed that using `<BlazorEnableTimeZoneSupport>false</BlazorEnableTimeZoneSupport>` would cause binding `@Datetime.Now` to display time of the machine where the client is running, however it displays UTC time.

How does it know what UTC time it is if it does not have time zone file? Is there a workaround to get local machine time?

I don't need UTC time or time zone conversions and would like to save few hundred kB of download by disabling time zone support.